# Extract data between two dates from an Excel table into another Excel table?

Tags: excel-tables

**Scenario:**
I have two named tables in the Excel with common column "date":

1. "MonthlySheet[date]"
2. "WorkShiftAll[date]"

lets take a look into the sample data-set:

[image]

I'm trying to index dynamically all records from the `WorkShiftAll[date]`which are between two dates defined into two different named cells: `PayPeriodStartDate` and `PayPeriodEndDate` into the `MonthlySheet[date]` using this formula (Shift+Ctrl+Enter):

```
=IF(ROWS(C$10:C10)>(SUMPRODUCT((WorkShiftAll[date]>=PayPeriodStartDate)*(WorkShiftAll[date]<=PayPeriodEndDate))),"",INDEX(workShiftsDateRange,SMALL(IF((WorkShiftAll[date]>=PayPeriodStartDate)*(WorkShiftAll[date]<=PayPeriodEndDate),ROW(WorkShiftAll[date])-ROW(WorkShiftAll[date])+1),ROWS(C$10:C10))))
```

where the `C10` is the first empty space in the `MonthlySheet` table. And `(SUMPRODUCT((WorkShiftAll[date]>=PayPeriodStartDate)*(WorkShiftAll[date]<=PayPeriodEndDate)))` is the formula I used to count how many records meets my criteria (being between two dates)

**PROBLEM:**
Two records are successfully listed for the month of October as it's recorded in the data-set, however, it repeats the SMALL (the first record) twice! not Friday October 26 and October 29.

[image]

When, I use a range, instead of the column for addressing the INDEX, it works!!
like if I use:

`INDEX(**WorkShifts!A2:A14**,SMALL(IF((WorkShiftAll[date]>=PayPeriodStartDate)`...
 It works and two record, 26 & 29 october appears. But I need my range be Dynamic so I want to use a Table. Should I convert it to a range? and there is no other way?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that we need to use the `[#Headers]` for deducting the first-previous-row of each current-calculating-row when the source of the data is a Table and not a defined range where the row number is constant:

```
ROW(WorkShiftAll[date])-ROW(WorkShiftAll[#Headers])),ROWS(C$10:C10))))
```

So the full resolving formula would be:

```
=IF(ROWS(C$10:C10)>(SUMPRODUCT((WorkShiftAll[date]>=PayPeriodStartDate)*(WorkShiftAll[date]<=PayPeriodEndDate))),"",INDEX(workShiftsDateRange,SMALL(IF((WorkShiftAll[date]>=PayPeriodStartDate)*(WorkShiftAll[date]<=PayPeriodEndDate),ROW(WorkShiftAll[date])-ROW(WorkShiftAll[#Headers])),ROWS(C$10:C10))))
```